# Не происходит условный переход

Tags: ассемблер

Вроде бы простейшая задача на ввод-вывод строки, но, почему-то, не происходит условный переход при достижении строкой определенной длинны. Как я только не пробовал: и через, и через . Не Прерывает он цикл. Вот одна из неработающих реализаций проблемной процедуры:

```
Input:
    mov ah,2
    mov dh,[string]
    mov dl,[column]
    mov bh,2
    int 10h

    mov si,[len]
    mov di,line
    inputLoop:
        mov ah,0
        int 16h

        cmp al,13
        jz endInput
        mov [di],al
        mov ah,9
        mov bh,2
        mov bl,[color]
        mov cx,1
        int 10h

        add di,2
        inc dx
        mov ah,2
        mov bh,2
        int 10h

        dec si
        cmp si,0
        jnz inputLoop
    endInput:
ret
```

Comment: А может просто ничего не видно? Вывод же на 2 страницу идёт.

Comment: @klopp, видно. Идет ввод символов, их запись в массив и вывод. 
Вывод видно, только он должен прерываться в один момент, когда поднимается флаг нуля
    cmp si,0

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, вы просто запарываете код или память вот этим: `add di,2`. После чего всё идёт не так, как хотелось бы. Вот прекрасно работающий пример (явные недочёты исправлять не стал).

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

Input:
    mov ah,2
    mov dh,[string]
    mov dl,[column]
    mov bh,2
    int 10h

    mov si,len
    mov di,offset line

inputLoop:

    mov ah,0
    int 16h

    cmp al,13
    jz endInput
    mov [di],al
    mov ah,9
    mov bh,2
    mov bl,[color]
    mov cx,1
    int 10h

    inc di; add di,2
    inc dx
    mov ah,2
    mov bh,2
    int 10h

    dec si
    jnz inputLoop

endInput:
    ret

string  db  1
column  db  2
color   db  7
line    db  0,0,0
len     equ $-offset line

END Input
```

И научитесь наконец-то пользоваться отладчиком! В нём вы найдёте ответы на все свои вопросы куда быстрей, чем гадая на кофейной гуще здесь.

[image]

Comment: Проблема в том, что я так и не понял, как обрабатывать прерывания в TD.

Comment: А каким боком тут прерывания? Вы ж не хотите сказать, что код не работает из-за прерываний :)

Comment: mov si,len
В этой строчке была проблема. len, размерностью в байт записывался в SI, размерностью 2 байта. Таким образом, старший байт SI оставался без изменения, а число в нем получалось очень большое.

Comment: Интересно, какой ассемблер слопал такую конструкцию? Насчёт masm и fasm не знаю, но tasm и nasm не скомпилируют `mov si,[len]`, если `len` определено как байт. А nasm вообще `mov si,len` (без скобок) всегда интерпретирует как `mov si,offset len`.